# libcurl: http response status code always NULL?

Tags: c, http, curl, libcurl

I am using libcurl 7.29.0.

All my test cases are working fine when the server is running, but when the server is not reachable I'm receiving a `CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR` error.

In this scenario I'm always getting a `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT` curl error and the HTTP response code is `0`.

Based on my requirement I want the HTTP response code. Please suggest some solution thank in advance.

Below is attached the API I'm using to post data.

```
int http_curl_post_response(char *url, char *post_data, char *response,
                            long int *responseCode) {
    CURL *ps_curl;
    CURLcode curl_status = CURLE_OK;
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL; /* http headers to send with request */

    /* get a curl handle */
    ps_curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (ps_curl) {
        /* set content type */
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");

        /* This is to intialize respone from curl */
        http_curl_respone ps_response;

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_data);

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, -1L);

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* This is to read response from curl */
        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_response_json);

        init_response(&ps_response);
        if (ps_response.pi1_response == NULL) {
            i4_curl_status = MEM_ALLOC_ERROR;
            goto HTTP_CURL_ERROR;
        }

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ps_response);

        curl_easy_setopt(ps_curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, i4_curl_status will get the return code */
        curl_status = curl_easy_perform(ps_curl);
        if (curl_status != CURLE_OK) {
            if (curl_status == CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR) {
                curl_easy_getinfo(ps_curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE,
                                  responseCode);
                /* always cleanup */
                curl_easy_cleanup(ps_curl);
            }
            goto HTTP_CURL_ERROR;
        } else {
            memcpy(response, ps_response.pi1_response, ps_response.s_len);
            response[ps_response.s_len] = '\0';
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(ps_curl);
        /* free headers */
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);

    HTTP_MEM_ERROR:
        if (ps_response.pi1_response) free(ps_response.pi1_response);
    } else {
        curl_status = CURLE_FAILED_INIT;
    }

HTTP_CURL_ERROR:

    return curl_status;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning `i4_curl_status` (which, incidentally, I don't see being declared anywhere) - but then testing `curl_status`. Is this a typo?

Comment: BTW: I would suggest removing the `node.js` and `c++` tags on this question, and perhaps trying a newer version of `libcurl` if possible. (Version 7.29 is from approx. six years ago: https://curl.haxx.se/download/ .)

Comment: @DavidCollins ya correct this is typo mistake, functionality wise no issue is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

> ... but when the server is not reachable I'm receiving a CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR error.
> In this scenario I'm always getting a CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT curl error and the HTTP response code is 0.

It doesn't even make sense to examine the response code if the server is not reachable and the connection failed. The [response code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) is a *property of the HTTP response*. It is recorded in part of the HTTP response (the [*status line*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.2)) that the HTTP server sends back in reply to the HTTP request that `libcurl` sends on your behalf. If there is no connection, the server did not receive your request and there is no response to speak of!

> Based on my requirement I want the HTTP response code.

If there is no connection, there is no response - and hence no response code.

In this scenario, you could set your *local* `responseCode` variable to `-1` to indicate connection failure:

```
*responseCode = -1;
```

Comment: is there any possibility to get 404 error when server is down or not reachable , because each post request i'm using new connection.

Comment: @Mehulpatel: In the absence of an _actual_ response from the server, you _could_ 'fake' a response code by setting your local `responseCode` variable to some legitimate value (such as 404). But I think this is misleading - as it might trick users of your API in to thinking that a connection had actually been established even if it hasn't. That's why I suggested using `-1` in this instance: it can't be confused with a legitimate status code.

Comment: I agree with @DavidCollins on this. libcurl returns 0 for this case since zero can't be confused with a legitimate status either. All proper HTTP status codes are 100 or larger.